# Find Common Denominator for 2 Fractions with JavaScript - Simplify & Improve

Tags: javascript

I wrote a JavaScript that takes 2 fractions and finds the common denominator for both. If the user inputs 2/6 and 1/2 --- the script outputs 2/6 + 3/6. I'm interested in feedback on possibly simplifying it or improving it. Thanks.

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/omelen/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
window.onload = function() {

    // Finds the highest common factor of 2 numbers
    function highestCommonFactor(a, b) {
        if (b == 0) {
            return a;
        }

        return highestCommonFactor(b, (a % b));
    }

    // Input fractions to add ////////////////////////////////
    // Fraction 1 = 2/6
    var fraction1Numerator = 2;
    var fraction1Denominator = 6;

    // Fraction 2 = 1/2
    var fraction2Numerator = 1;
    var fraction2Denominator = 2;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Find the highest common factor of both denominators
    var factor = highestCommonFactor(fraction1Denominator, fraction2Denominator); // 2

    if (factor > 1) { // There's a common factor greater than 1
        if (fraction1Denominator > fraction2Denominator) {
            // Find out how many times the factor goes into bigger denominator
            var temp = fraction1Denominator / factor;

            fraction2Numerator  = fraction2Numerator * temp;
            fraction2Denominator = fraction2Denominator * temp;
        } else {
            // Find out how many times the factor goes into bigger denominator
            var temp = fraction2Denominator / factor;

            fraction1Numerator  = fraction1Numerator * temp;
            fraction1Denominator = fraction1Denominator * temp;
        }
    } else { // There's no common factor greater than 1 so we need to multiple each fraction by each others denominators
        // Temp values
        var fraction1NumeratorTemp = fraction1Numerator;
        var fraction1DenominatorTemp = fraction1Denominator;

        fraction1Numerator  = fraction1Numerator * fraction2Denominator;
        fraction1Denominator = fraction1Denominator * fraction2Denominator;

        fraction2Numerator  = fraction2Numerator * fraction1DenominatorTemp;
        fraction2Denominator = fraction2Denominator * fraction1DenominatorTemp;
    }

    // Display solution
    document.getElementById("divSolution").innerText = fraction1Numerator + "/" + fraction1Denominator + " + " + fraction2Numerator + "/" + fraction2Denominator;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="divSolution"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt to help you.

- As a general rule, keep everything as general as you can and don't split your code into different cases unless you have to. From the `if (factor >1)` part, I knew things could be improved
- At the end, the denominators will be the Least Common Multiple of the two initial fractions.
- Then, you just need to multiply the numerators by the same amount used to multiply the denominators

Here's the corresponding code.

```
// Finds the highest common factor of 2 numbers
function highestCommonFactor(a, b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    }
    return highestCommonFactor(b, a%b);
}
function leastCommonMultiple(a,b) {
    return a*b/(highestCommonFactor(a,b));
}

// Input fractions to add ////////////////////////////////
// Fraction 1 = 2/6
var fraction1Numerator = 2;
var fraction1Denominator = 6;

// Fraction 2 = 1/2
var fraction2Numerator = 1;
var fraction2Denominator = 2;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Find the highest common factor of both denominators
var commonMultiple = leastCommonMultiple(fraction1Denominator, fraction2Denominator); 

fraction1Numerator   *= (commonMultiple / fraction1Denominator);
fraction2Numerator   *= (commonMultiple / fraction2Denominator);

// Display solution
document.getElementById("divSolution").innerText = fraction1Numerator + "/" + commonMultiple + " + " + fraction2Numerator + "/" + commonMultiple;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my code. I tried your revised code but had some issues... I inputted the following fractions and got the following incorrect results...Fraction 1 = 1/2 --> 1/6
Fraction 2 = 2/6 --> 6/6;

Fraction 1 = 2/12 --> 2/36
Fraction 2 = 1/18 --> 6/36;

Fraction 1 = 1/18 --> 1/36
Fraction 2 = 2/12 --> 12/26.

Comment: I changed the following 2 lines of your code: fraction2Numerator   *= (commonMultiple / fraction1Denominator);
fraction2Numerator   *= (commonMultiple / fraction2Denominator); --- TO ---> numeratorMultipler1 = commonMultiple / fraction1Denominator;
numeratorMultipler2 = commonMultiple / fraction2Denominator;

fraction1Numerator = numeratorMultipler1 * fraction1Numerator;
fraction2Numerator = numeratorMultipler2 * fraction2Numerator; And that fixed the issue. Let me know what you think?

Comment: Actually, you just need to change :
fraction2Numerator   *= (commonMultiple / fraction1Denominator);
for
fraction1Numerator   *= (commonMultiple / fraction1Denominator);
(one character is to be changed)

Comment: Also, I think before programming anything, you should try to do your calculation with a pen and paper and try to figure out what you are doing. Then, once everything's clear, you can open your favorite text editor.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks. I started learning JavaScript a few months ago, I appreciate your feedback, especially on how I can make my code clearer and more efficient. I plan on posting a few more similar fraction/decimal codes for review and would like your feedback if you have time.

Comment: I'm ready when you are ;-)